# IFrame Overlaps Div in IE (Working fine in Chrome)

Tags: css, html, iframe

I have written some code where a div should overlap IFrame. In Chrome its working fine, where as in IE IFrame overlaps div. Below is the code. Any idea on how to fix this issue such that it works fine with both IE and Chrome?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>IFrame Div</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div top="86px" left="5px" width="500px" height="500px" z-index="20000" style="width: 1000px;
            border-color: red; height: 500px; position: absolute !important; border-color: red;
            left: 5px; top: 86px; border-width: 5px; background-color: #E6E6E6; opacity: .8;">
        </div>
        <iframe src="http://samplepdf.com/sample.pdf" height="700px" width="600px"></iframe>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the iframe: `z-index:-999;`

Or you could use in-line CSS: `<iframe src="http://samplepdf.com/sample.pdf" height="700px" width="600px" style="z-index:-999;"></iframe>`

Comment: try also adding a positive z-index to the div `z-index:999;` see if that helps

Comment: What version of IE are you having the problem in?

Comment: It didn't work in IE 8 too. You can try by saving the above code in html file.

Comment: Can you post the code which worked for you in IE8? Also which Operating System ur using?

Comment: I used the exact same code you posted in your question. I'm using windows 7.